# ButterKnife Bind not found after migrating to AndroidX

Tags: android, bind, androidx, butterknife

After migrating to AndroidX, I updated ButterKnife to latest version 10.2.0

But when building,

I am getting this error

```
error: cannot find symbol class Bind
```

I tried by adding

```
compileOptions {
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

But it also didn't help.

I saw an answer to make the minSdkVersion at least 15, it is already 16 in my case.

Here is my build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 12
        versionName "2.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        incremental true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


repositories {
    jcenter()
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.valdesekamdem.library:md-toast:0.9.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.0'

    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'

    implementation 'com.github.badoualy:stepper-indicator:1.0.7'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: There is an issue located here on this: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1571

Comment: @DanielWilson I got the answer buddy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check this [link](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1280#issuecomment-401605660)

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
}

dependencies {
   implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
   annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @BindView(R.id.text_view)
    TextView mTextView;
```

it's successful.

I fix the @Bind to @BindView, it's successful too.
But why did they make such a drastic change?
I had to redo my entire project because of that.

Comment: You also have to update from R.id ... to R2.id

Answer (score 0):

In my case as suggested in [this comment](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1571#issuecomment-563420138) I have just added these dependencies in the app-level `build.gradle` file

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.0'
```

And in project-level `build.gradle` file declare the following

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. 
android {
  ...
  // Butterknife requires Java 8.
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
  annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
}

 2. To use Butter Knife in a library, add the plugin to your buildscript:

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:10.2.3'
  }
}

 3. and then apply it in your module:
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'

 4. Now make sure you use R2 instead of R inside all Butter Knife annotations.
class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
  @BindView(R2.id.user) EditText username;
  @BindView(R2.id.pass) EditText password;
...
}
```